# TFS 2012 backup database restore in TFS 2014

Tags: sql-server, tfs-2015

I had TFS 2012 and I wanted to upgrade it to 2015. According to the MSDN website this shouldn't be a problem, except when I do it (...)

Before I started I made backups of the configuration database and the project collections.
I downloaded TFS 2015 and executed the setup, allowing the setup to upgrade my 2012. It resulted in an error and I lost everything (except for the backups of course).

I didn't panic at all and thought: I will remove 2015, reinstall 2012 again and put back the backups. Good thinking, right? Except for the point that I ran SQL 2014 and the installation of TFS 2012 does not allow SQL 2014 (What the... ?).

(Re)installing SQL 2012 had no point either, since the backups where made in 2014.

Still no panic...

Next thing I tried was to reinstall SQL 2014 and TFS 2015. Setup the collection I needed and tried to restore the backed up database... The only thing I saw were errors. Atleast I tried, right?

So, here I am... A little panic has submerged now.

Is there any way to get all the information stored in the back (SQL 2014 database for TFS 2012) to my TFS 2014 environment?

Comment: How did you have TFS2012 with SQL2014 (when you backup the databases)?

Comment: Can you provide some of the errors.
It sounds like you did a in place upgrade, which should definitely not result in you "loosing everything"

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore the backed up database first. Then configure  TFS2015 associate with SQL2014. You should use the **upgrade** option in Team Foundation Server Configuration Center to achieve it.

If you get errors during the upgrade, please provide the detail info of those errors and which step you are stuck in.

Answer (score 1):

Still easier, install tfs 2015 freshly pointing to a empty fresh sql 2015 installation.
 After completion, restore the collection dbs only  on sql 2014. dont restore tfs_configuration.

hope u detached them in 2012 , before backing up.
Now go to tfs 2015 admin console and attach collection menu.
If the db appears, it was detachedand restored properly. 
Attach the collectiondbs one by one.
Else u have to run tfsconfig / repair in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost the same as: [Copy TFS 2012 collection to another server with TFS 2015 Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553648/copy-tfs-2012-collection-to-another-server-with-tfs-2015-installed/38564407#38564407)

Follow the same steps but skip the reattach step for the original collection.